# Auto create unexisting columns when using python pandas to insert MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

Use pandas dataframe internal function to insert data to mysql is quite simple, like following:

```
df.to_sql(name="test", con=engine, if_exists="append", index=False, index_label=False)
```

But the problem is, if `df` has the column that is not already in database table `test`, it will report an error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1054, "Unkonwn column 'column_A' in 'field list'")

My stupid idea is to compare the columns in `df` and `test`, and create the unexisting columns.
Is there any other elegant way?

Comment: That's not a stupid idea. Allowing columns just to be created with no guardrails could lead to all sorts of problems

Comment: @roganjosh The exciting thing is that when the table does not exist, same insert command will create columns automatically, so I think maybe there is some command can do it similarly even the table has been already created. Then what I need to do is just to refine columns periodically.